# How can a text field be re-sized by touch and drag with finger in Smartphone devices

Tags: theming

Hello Drupal Masters,

I have used Bootstrap template for my Drupal 7 website. 
When in Smartphone devices such as iPhone or Samsung phones, i tried to touch the screen using my finger to drag to resize the text field vertically (see screenshot) [image]larger, so the text field could display all text simultaneously.

Whatever i do, I can't re-size the text field when using my finger. It works only with a mouse.

Does anyone know to make the field realizable in touch mode using fingers?

Thank you very much in advance for you tips & Tricks.

Regards
Kim

Answer (score 1):

You might need to implement a custom module that just loads a library similar to this one:

http://interactjs.io/

Scroll down to the resizing section and then check out the demo. You could presumably do this for your input fields.

Comment: Thank you very much Bryden, i appreciate your answer very much..